# Load ajax var into bootstrap modal which is loading from another php page

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have multiple modals on one page, all of which have unique ids. When a user clicks a button it opens the unique modal.

`<button id="<?php echo $removeslash; ?>" class="btn btn-primary open-modal" data-source="output.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span> Open Modal</button>`

As you can see the body of the modal is in output.php, this is because im running a script in output.php which creates unique data depending which button has been clicked. Im trying to pass `id="<?php echo $removeslash; ?>"` to output.php via ajax. Here is ajax below.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#modalResult .modal-body").load($(this).data("source"), function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            console.log("unable to load content : " + xhr.status);
        } else {
            $("#modalResult").modal("show");
        }

    });
    var mehmeh = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "output.php",
        data: ({
            'id': mehmeh
        }),

        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        }
    });

});
```

The ajax code works okay I think because the success function displays with the button id in. But when the modal loads, it wont load. Here is the echo code in the output.php file.

```
<h1>FooBar: <?php echo $_REQUEST['id']; ?></h1>
```

Im sure it has something to do with the modal loading on index.php but ajax giving the data to output.php, but i cant figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the javascript error in console? And if you see an error than can you show it?

Comment: Hi, yeah not getting any java script errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to fix this problem, it might be pretty sloppy but here it is.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open-modal", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    e.preventDefault();
    $("#modalResult .modal-body").load($(this).data("source"), function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            console.log("unable to load content : " + xhr.status);
        } else {
            $.post("output.php", {
                    id: id
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    $("#modalResult").modal("show");
                    $('.modal-body').html(data);
                })
        }

    });
});
```